# Mule ESB Multiple when conditions in Dataweave

Tags: mule, esb, dataweave

I am using dataweave, due to sales taxes in each state, I need to assign a each customer from a specific state to a pre-defined user.
However when I create this in dataweave I end up with this as my XML:

```
<Customer>
<Number>
  <Number>
    <Number>
      <Number>WEB002</Number>
    </Number>
  </Number>
</Number>
```

I just need one 'number' node underneath the 'customer' node. 
Here is my dataweave:

```
Customer:{
Number: 'WEB001' when payload.order.billing_address.state == 'Indiana' otherwise
Number: 'WEB002' when payload.order.billing_address.state == 'Kentucky' otherwise
Number: 'WEB003' when payload.order.billing_address.state == 'Illinois' otherwise
Number: 'WEB004'
},
```

Have tried placing my conditions inside of brackets, no joy, have tried to wrap each condition in brackets, no joy. 
Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can put the mapping between state and number in a map/dictionary which would improve the readability like this:

```
%var numbers = {
    Indiana: 'WEB001',
    Kentucky: 'WEB002',
    Illinois: 'WEB003'
}
```

this is what your dataweave would look like:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml

%var defaultNumber = 'WEB004'
%var numbers = {
    Indiana: 'WEB001',
    Kentucky: 'WEB002',
    Illinois: 'WEB003'
}

---
Customer: {
    Number: numbers[payload.order.billing_address.state] 
        default defaultNumber
}
```

and here is a screenshot containing sample data and the resulting preview:
[image]

Answer (score 8):

A very easy and simple way to do that as follows:-

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:input-payload doc:sample="empty.xml" />
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0

    %output application/xml
     ---
   {
      Customer: 
       Number:  "WEB001" when payload.order.billing_address.state == "Indiana" 
       otherwise (
         "WEB002" when payload.order.billing_address.state == "Kentucky"
             otherwise (
             "WEB003" when payload.order.billing_address.state == "Illinois"
                 otherwise "WEB004"))
   }

   ]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
```